# When to create a procedure(sub, function)

Tags: vb.net, function, procedure

I'm currently creating my application and I'd like to write an understandable code.
I'd like to know when to create a procedure. If it affects the performance of my application if I created much.

Here is my sample:

*Sample Code:*

**With Sub**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Greetings()
End Sub

Private sub Greetings()
MessageBox.Show("Hello!")
    MessageBox.Show("To")
    MessageBox.Show("My")
    MessageBox.Show("World")
End
```

In the example above, assume that this sub will only be called 1 - 2 times in the whole application. I like to easily understand my code.

*Versus*
**Without Sub**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!")
    MessageBox.Show("To")
    MessageBox.Show("My")
    MessageBox.Show("World")
End Sub
```

In the example above, this piece of code too my time to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should create subroutines when the logic is going to be used multiple times, especially if it's being used in multiple places.

If you ever have to change code, you want to only change it ONCE.

Performance with running basic code or calling functions is a non-issue. Do not even consider it.

Comment: Does too many subroutines affects the runtime of the application?

Comment: No. Applications will invariably have thousands of subroutines. How many you have is irrelevant.